# redux-api-middleware How to do global settings for endpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-api-middleware, redux-middleware

In `redux-api-middleware` we can create a API call like below,

```
export function loadUsers() {
  return {
    [CALL_API]: {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      endpoint: 'http://localhost:1337/users',
      method: 'GET',
      types: [LOAD_USERS_REQUEST, LOAD_USERS_SUCCESS, LOAD_USERS_FAILURE]
    }
  }
}
```

Problem is, for every request, am using the **common end point** `http://localhost:1337` , **Header content type and authorization token**  settings.

I need a place to set those settings globally, from their official documentation am unable to find the solution. Anybody know this? or have any idea to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In middleware you can get the access to the store state, so you can put token and other auth information into the store and then use it in middleware.

I had the same issue and had ended with implementation like this:

```
const callApiMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  // skip everything which is not API call
  const callAPI = action[CALL_API]
  if (typeof callAPI === 'undefined') {
    return next(action);
  }

  // the session info from store
  const session = store.getState().session;

  // perform request
  const {endpoint, headers, method} = callAPI;
  return fetch(endpoint, {
    headers: Object.assign({
        Authorization: `Bearer ${session && session.token}`
        // you can add more default headers there if you would like so
    }, headers),
    method
  });
};
```

Comment: I got it, this is an our custom middleware, we should add this store by ```applyMiddleware``` method? right?

Comment: Yes, this is custom middleware. You can find something similar in redux examples: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/src/middleware/api.js

Comment: Nice! @just-boris. What if you need dynamic headers besides the Authorization jwt one? Meaning that one can't know in advance what the headers will be so you can't set them in a custom middleware. Is there anyway to merge dynamic ones with pre-defined ?